# Why is my prop not being passed in correctly in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using a `ProductCard` component to pass the `product` prop to a page called "ProductPage". The `product` is supposed to be an object with an id, categoryId, name, price, and img key/value pairs. I'm using a combination of filtering and mapping on my array of products to get the specific product by the id and passing the whole object to render on the "ProductPage". Like so,

Products Page

```
const ProductsPage = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const [categoryId, setCategoryId] = useState(0);

  const show = (id) => {
    if (toggle === id) return setToggle(null);

    setToggle(id);
    setCategoryId(id);
  };

  return (
    <div className="products-page">
      <div className="container">
        <section className="product-banner">
          <h3>All Products</h3>
        </section>
        <div className="product-categories">
          {categories.map((cat) => (
            <div key={cat.id}>
              <section
                onClick={() => show(cat.id)}
                className="cat-toggle"
              >
                <h4>{cat.name}</h4>
              </section>
              {toggle === cat.id && (
                <section className="products">
                  {products.filter((item) => item.categoryId === categoryId).map(filteredProduct => (
                    <ProductCard key={filteredProduct.id} product={filteredProduct} />
                  ))}
                </section>
              )}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

At this current moment when I log the `product` I'm getting "undefined" and nothing is being rendered on the product page.

The `ProductCard` component goes as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./ProductCard.scss";

const ProductCard = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <Link className="link" to={`/products/${product.id}`}>
      <div className="product-card">
        <div className="product-img">
          <img src={product.img} alt={product.name} />
        </div>
        <div className="product-info">
          <p>${product.price}</p>
          <h5>{product.name}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

Since I'm using react-router-dom `Link` I tried to pass in the props via state={{ product: {product} }} within the Link's props but that gave me the same result.

Comment: I see no issue here with the `products` filtering & mapping; it should result in defined `filteredProduct` object references. If it didn't then there'd be an exception thrown when trying to set the mapped React key `filteredProduct.id`. What is the value of `products.filter((item) => item.categoryId === categoryId)`? Could you create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: I don't mind but I found out how to fix the bug by using the useParam() to get my productId and then fetch the product

Comment: Sure. It doesn't fix the props issue, but getting the id from params and refetching data is a solution. It's not the best one, but it is one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the product via props I simply used the useParams() hook from react-router-dom to get the ID from the url and then searched my product data for the specific products like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import { products } from "../../resources/products"

import "./ProductPage.scss";

const ProductPage = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  
  const selectedProduct = products.find(product => product.id === Number(id))

  return (
    <div className='product-page'>
      {selectedProduct.name}
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductPage
```